# How to fill the data frame with using the match between columns and column list and value list using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6     col7
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

the values from col2 to col7 are empty now, Now I have two lists,

```
list1=[['col2'],['col5','col6'],[],['col3','col4','col5','col6'],['col7','col4']]
list2=[['1'],['2','3'],[],['4','5','6','7'],['8','9']]
```

I want to fill the data frame if the column names matches with list with the corresponding values with list2

The result df should look like,

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6     col7
 1       1       NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
 2       NA      NA      NA      2       3        NA
 3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
 4       NA       4       5       6      7        NA
 5       NA      NA       9      NA      NA       8
```

How to do it in most efficient way using pandas, python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I will do

```
df.update(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=[z],columns=y,index=[x]) for x , (y, z) in enumerate(zip(list1,list2))]))
df
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0     1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     2  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3  NaN
2     3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     4  NaN    4    5    6    7  NaN
4     5  NaN  NaN    9  NaN  NaN    8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use loop solution with zip and enumerate for counter:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    df.loc[i, a] = b

print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0     1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     2  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3  NaN
2     3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     4  NaN    4    5    6    7  NaN
4     5  NaN  NaN    9  NaN  NaN    8
```

Or try create 3 column DataFrame and then `pivot`:

```
a = [(i, a1, b1) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) for a1, b1 in zip(a, b)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a).pivot(0,1,2)
print (df1)
1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0                              
0    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3  NaN
3  NaN    4    5    6    7  NaN
4  NaN  NaN    9  NaN  NaN    8
```

and then [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df[['col1']].join(df1)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0     1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     2  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3  NaN
2     3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     4  NaN    4    5    6    7  NaN
4     5  NaN  NaN    9  NaN  NaN    8
```

Answer (score 1):

With simple loop:

```
In [54]: for i, col_names in enumerate(list1): 
    ...:     df.loc[i, col_names] = list2[i] 
    ...:         
    ...:                                                                                                             

In [55]: df                                                                                                          
Out[55]: 
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
0     1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     2  NaN  NaN  NaN    2    3  NaN
2     3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     4  NaN    4    5    6    7  NaN
4     5  NaN  NaN    9  NaN  NaN    8
```